# Is there a way to automatically re-send an email according to certain rules with Outlook 2007 and MS Exchange?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, workflow, exchange-server

I am looking for a solution to the following problem:

My manager wants to automatically send a second message when he sends an email to X and there is no response in two days. If there is no further response in 2 more days, send another message.

Before I start building anything, I wonder if there is already a product/solution that does that? Can anybody recommend an already existing tool?

We use MS Exchange and he uses Outlook 2007.

Comment: The most products I am looking at, you can customize your auto-reply and do all sorts of fancy things, but not the thing I want. I can't find a tool on which you can apply a rule based on which the auto reply is triggered.

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'm looking at a similar-ish project to resend service quotations if no response on our in-house system

Comment: I can't imagine there's no solution for that already...

Comment: Is that really a coding question? It seems to me it would be a better fit for SuperUser or ServerFault depending on the scope (client side or server side).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Auto Follow Up](http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/outlook/follow-up-email.html) is a tool I've used in the past for this specific purpose. Also, always check www.slipstick.com for listings of Outlook/Exchange add-ins - they seem to be the best source (disclaimer: I have *no affiliation* with that site or any of its add-ins)

Answer (score 1):

Would this solve your problem:

http://www.followupthen.com/

Perhaps not exactly what you want and it isn't integrated into Outlook.

Comment: Daniel, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: I know, I know. In email-mode and slightly too fast for myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an existing solution, but in case you don't get any answers:

You can use [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) to do this: pointing it at his Sent Items folder. So this is basically what you would do:

- Use [`SyncFolderItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563967%28v=EXCHG.140%29.aspx) against his Sent Items, say every 1 hour. The first time you do this use `null` as the `SyncState`, thereafter use the last `SyncState` the server sent you.

  1. Write them to a SQL table: `{ ItemId NVARCHAR(MAX), ChangeKey NVARCHAR(MAX), MessageID NVARCHAR(MAX), Sent DATETIME }`. `MessageID` would be the `Message-ID` header from the message.
  2. Run a query (say once a day) that selects the rows where the `Sent` value is more than 2 days ago.
  3. Use [`GetItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa565934%28v=EXCHG.140%29.aspx) to retrieve the original mail and resend (first clearing/deleting `Message-ID`) it using [`SendItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa580238%28v=EXCHG.140%29.aspx).
  4. Delete the selected rows.
  5. These items will land up in the Sent Items folder and will be picked up by your application (as they are actually new mails); and re-processed in 2 days.
- Use `SyncFolderItems` against his Inbox, again maybe every hour (maybe immediately after the first operation against Sent Items). Keep a unique `SyncState` for this operation.

  1. Grab the `In-Reply-To` header. Delete any rows with a maching `MessageID`.
  2. Grab the `References` header; and split it into a list. Delete any rows with a matching `MessageID`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will find exactly what you want. This is functionality which belongs to a CRM, not to email software.

Having said that, the [Getting Things Done Outlook Add-In](https://gtdsupport.netcentrics.com/home/) will get you in that direction. It won't automatically send a follow up mail, but it can take care of a notification so you send it yourself. (but this plugin is not free - $75 - you have to decide yourself if that's worth it)

With the GTD add-in you can send a mail, and select the option "Send and Action". After pressing send mail, you can select the action "@Waiting For", and press ok. Now it will create an outlook task, with the subject and contents of the email you sent automatically filled. You can set all the task properties, like end date and notification time.

After two days at the notification time, you get a (default) outlook popup, where you can open the task. With one click you can open the corresponding email and use reply or forward to send your followup. You can create a new task or modify the existing task for the next followup.

If you receive a reply in the mean time, and open the mail, you can use the "related task" button to find the corresponding task to mark it as complete. It also adds buttons like defer and delegate to your mail.

There is a 30-day trial. I am not connected to netcentrics, but I have bought and use this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into automating Outlook using Visual Basic for Applications? If you aren't familiar with VBA, or if the thought of writing VBA gives you nightmares (I've had a few), then you might find some example VBA code on the web that accomplishes something similar to what you are trying to do, and then you could just tweak it. I know you said that you wanted an existing tool, but I thought I would throw this out there as a sort of last resort. It's not ideal, but I'm pretty sure it would solve your problem.

Comment: I wanted to see first if somebody else made something similar or if there is already something like that on the market. I'd rather avoid VB, but if nothing else is left. The other problem is, I am not exactly allowed to install random applications on the Exchange server, so if I find client solution would be great. Else I make one.